# JavaScript Formula Incorrectly Calculating (Implementation, syntax, or PEMDAS error likely?)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a function that should take information about monthly mortgage payment amount, interest rate, downpayment, etc. and spit out the cost of home that the user could hypothetically afford.

The formula ([I think...](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/97830/formula-for-potential-home-value-from-monthly-mortgage)) is this:
[image]

And I have it in JS like this:

```
  function formatMoney(number, c, d, t) {
      var n = number,
      c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
      d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
      t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
      s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
      i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))),
      j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
     return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
   };

  function calculateCost()
  {
    var cost = downpayment + ( monthly * ( Math.pow( 1 + ( interest / 12 ), term * 12 ) - 1 ) / ( ( interest / 12 ) * ( Math.pow( 1 + ( interest / 12 ), term * 12 ) ) ) );
    cost = "$" + formatMoney(cost, 2, ".", ",")
    return cost;
  }
```

But it's spitting out answers that are way too big to be logical.  Can anyone familiar with JS figure out where I'm going wrong, translating the formula to JS?

Comment: One issue is that you're using `parseInt()` after calling `.toFixed()`, which will lose any fractional part.

Comment: Do you really think someone is able to follow that `c`, `s` ... ? Why not just give them proper names?

Comment: What values are you using for variables `downpayment`, `monthly`, `interest`, and `term`?

Comment: @RickHitchcock I tried it with $20,000 downpayment, $1.500 monthly, a .05 interest rate, and a 30 year term and it spit out $20,000,279,422.43...which seems ridiculously high.

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with the same result.  Could you update your code with your values so that it shows what you get?